# Return filename if filenames contain same keyword and are of roughly the same file size

Tags: python, regex, list-comprehension

Spent a decent amount of time on this question already, and I feel that it should be relatively straight-forward, but I want to accomplish this in a computationally efficient and Pythonic manner.

I have created two lists: one containing the keyword associated with each filename, and another containing the file size of those respective files rounded to the nearest 25 bytes. I am attempting to identify duplicate files in a fairly rudimentary manner, and there may be some very small differences in the files themselves (in terms of text), but in general a simple file size comparison should do the trick.

My approach thus far is to iterate through the filenames, keywords and file sizes and return filenames with keywords and sizes that are repeated more than once. Note that my current implementation below does not require that the sizes that are repeated are necessarily associated with that specific keyword (but this is what I want: file duplicates should have roughly the same file size and definitely the same keyword). I think I am just overthinking this, but would utilizing a dictionary here be of use?

Some sample filenames include:

```
United States vs Mexico on 4142017.txt w/ file size of 5282 bytes
Mexico vs Uruguay on 3272016.txt w/ file size of 5684 bytes
Spain vs France on 4222017.txt w/ file size of 4883 bytes
United States vs Mexico on 4152017.txt w/ file size of 5276 bytes
```

Here is what I have thus far (I realize this does not work as is):

```
import os, re

path = 'Enter path here'; os.chdir(path)
folders = os.listdir(path)

for folder in folders[:3]:

    files = os.listdir(path + '\\' + folder); os.chdir(path + '\\' + folder)

    names = [re.findall(r'vs (.*) on', f)[0] for f in files]
    sizes = [os.stat(f).st_size for f in files]
    sizes = [int(25*round(float(s)/25)) for s in sizes]

    duplicates = [f for f, i, j in zip(files, names, sizes) if names.count(i)>1 and sizes.count(j)>1]

    print(duplicates)
```

The desired output would be a list like follows:

```
['United States vs Mexico on 4142017.txt','United States vs Mexico on 4152017.txt']
```

Comment: Can you write what th `names`, `sizes` look like at the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the canonical way to do this sort of thing is with [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), forming a dictionary with keys being a tuple of keyword and size, and values being the list of matching file name.

Mock-up example:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# input data as a list or sequence of tuples (keyword, size, filename):
entries = [('foo',3,'foo a'), ('bar',6,'bar b'), ('foo',3,'foo c')]

d = defaultdict(list)
for (k,v,f) in entries:
    d[(k,v)].append(f)

print [dupe for dupes in d.values() if len(dupes)>1 for dupe in dupes]
```

The file names corresponding to entries with more duplicated keyword–size pairs are then those entries in the dictionary with length greater than 1.

To iterate through the duplicates instead of explicitly creating the list, one could use `itertools.chain.from_iterable`.

This is not the most memory-efficient approach — by checking the dictionary as it is built, one can avoid storing all the matching filenames — but it has the benefit of simplicity

Comment: The general idea here gets me going on the right path, just some small adjustments for my specific application, thanks!